# Dynamic font size for NSTextField on macOS

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nstextfield

On iOS I can create a `UIFont` that automatically adapts to the font size chosen in the Settings app by the user:

```
label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

(Copy-pasted from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically/).) I couldn't find a similar API for macOS. In the Accessibility settings I can change the font size and some apps react to it, like System Settings and Finder automatically increase the labels. Is there a way to create `NSFont` or `NSTextField` that automatically adapts to the chosen font size?